# how to call a constant by a variable

Tags: php

I have a function which I use like this

```
$i18n_APP = new i18n($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'module/'.$modid.'/lang/lang_{LANGUAGE}.ini',        
$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'lang/langcache/', 'en');
$i18n_APP->setPrefix('APP'.$appid);
$i18n_APP->init();
```

Normally I call the function by the prefix, like this

```
APP($el)
```

Now I have to use a variable prefix, cause I use the $appid, so I can't code it like the way above.

Is there any way to make it in a dynamic way maybe like this
App.$appid($el)

Hope I could explain what I tried to do.

By the way, maybe I don't need to do it, if I find a way to "add" different languagefiles to the function. For the moment I initiate a new class for every languagefile.

Comment: This is PHP code, not Javascript/jQuery.

Comment: What are you trying to do?

Comment: i try to call the class dynamicaly like this  App.$appid($el)

Comment: No, that's your attempted solution. Why do you rely on dynamic calls? This seems to be an example of an [XY-problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/155138) to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find a way to solve it

```
function langtag($prefix, $value)
{
  return $prefix($value);
}
```

and

```
$moid=4;
echo langtag('APP'.$modid,$el)
```